# Inline sprintf() for defining string as num in C?

Tags: c, string, type-conversion, integer

So a bit ago I was warming up and doing some *very* simple challenges. I came across one on edabit where you need to make a function to add the digits of a number and tell if the resulting number is "Oddish" or "Evenish"
(ie `oddishOrEvenish(12) -> "Oddish"` because 1 + 2 = 3 and 3 is odd)
so I solved it with some simple code

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>

char* odOrEv(int num);
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    printf("%s", odOrEv(12));
}

char* odOrEv(int num) {
    char* strnum = (char*) malloc(11);
    char* tempchar = (char*) malloc(2); // ik i can declare on one line but this is neater
    int total = 0;
    sprintf(strnum, "%d", num);
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof strnum; i++) {
        tempchar[0] = strnum[i];
        total += (int) strtol(tempchar, (char**) NULL, 10);
    }
    if (total % 2 == 0) return "Evenish";
    return "Oddish";
}
```

and it worked first try! Pretty rudimentary but I did it. i then thought *hey this is fun howabout I make it better*, so I got it down to

```
# include "includes.h"

char* odOrEv(int num);
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    printf("%s", odOrEv(13));
}

char* odOrEv(int num) {
    char* strnum = (char*) malloc(11);
    int total = 0;
    sprintf(strnum, "%d", num);
    while (*strnum) total += (int) *strnum++;
    return total % 2 == 0 ? "Evenish" : "Oddish";
}
```

just 5 lines for the function. Since I'm so pedantic though, I hate that I have to define `strnum` on a different line than declaring it since I use `sprintf`. I've tried searching, but I couldn't find any functions to convert int to string that I could use while declaring the string (e.x. `char* strnum = int2str(num);`). So is there any way to cut off that one line?

srry if this was too big just tried to explain everything
P.S. don't tell to use `atoi()` or `stoi` or any of those since they bad (big reason long to eplain) also I'd prefer if I didn't have to include any more directories but it's fine if I do

EDIT: forgot quote added it

Comment: Hint: you don't need to convert to/from a string at all.

Comment: Why are you using malloc instead of `char strnum[11];`?

Comment: You need to set `tempchar[1] = '\0'` before using `strtol()`

Comment: You don't need to add the digits. You just need to count the odd digits. If there are an odd number of odd digits, the number is oddish.

Comment: @Barman adding digits will be more efficient than checking, adding and then checking

Comment: amazing56789, `strnum = (char*) malloc(11);` is insufficient space for `odOrEv(INT_MIN)`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I did that cuz 2147483647 is 10 digits + 1 for \0. I'm storing each as a char not a number, and chars are 1 byte each so it's enough for max in you can do (you can't even input a long)

Comment: @amazing56789  `INT_MIN` is often `-2147483648` and needs `char[12]` to form a _string_ `"-2147483648"`.

Comment: @Barmar the proper way to declare arrays is via pointers, and a lot of functions run on char pointers as strings + i dont think I cod do my while loop if I used static array declaration

Comment: @Barmar im pretty sure the sprintf does that automatically

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica ah I'll do 12 for that negative sign

Comment: *"i dont think I cod do my while loop if I used static array declaration"* True, you would need a for loop: `for (int i=0; strnum[i]; i++) total += strnum[i];`  The big benefit of using an array is that you don't have to remember to `free` it (something you forgot to do, and can't do, because at the end of the function you don't have the original pointer that `malloc` returned).

Comment: @amazing56789 The first snippet doesn't do pointer arithmetic, so there's no reason it needs to use malloc. You could also use a local array and then declare `char *ptr = &array[0];`, then increment `ptr`. `malloc()` should be used when the array's lifetime is beyond the function, or the array is too big for a local array, or you need to resize the array dynamically (with `realloc()`)

Answer (score 2):

To be honest it the one of the weirdest functions I have ever seen in my life.

You do not need strings, dynamic allocations and monster functions like sprintf or `strtol`.

```
char* odOrEv(int num) 
{
    int sum = 0;
    while(num)
    {
        sum += num % 10;
        num /= 10;
    }
    return sum % 2 == 0 ? "Evenish" : "Oddish";
}
```

Comment: Works even with negative `num`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually have to add the digits. The sum of even digits is always even, so you can ignore them. The sum of an odd number of odd digits is odd, the sum of an even number of odd digits is even. So just loop through the digits, alternating between oddish and evenish every time you see an odd digit.

You can loop through the digits by dividing the number by 10 and then checking whether the number is odd or even.

```
char *OddorEven(int num) {
    int isOdd = 0;
    while (num != 0) {
        if (num % 2 != 0) {
            isOdd = !isOdd;
        }
        num /= 10;
    }
    return isOdd ? "Oddish" : "Evenish";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I always forget that stupidity of %

Comment: `isOdd ^= num & 1U;` avoid the need for `%` or if branch in the loop.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Any decent compiler will optimize to the same code, and there's only so much cryptic bit-twiddling I'm willing to write into the C code.

Comment: Not clear which is more crytpic -- one line is easier to read.  Neither gcc nor clang will optimize to an xor, preferring a test+cmov for the if.

Comment: it will not compile

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: For a 1s complement machine to follow the standard, it needs to emulate 2s complement when converting `num` to unisgned to do the `&`, so it will work there too (it will just be a bit more expensive).  There's a reason 1s complement designs were almost never used.

Comment: @ChrisDodd   I was thinking of `num & 1`.

Comment: @ChrisDodd why so complicated if the simple sum will do the same without overcomplicated logic.

Comment: Because a simple sum is a simple sum.  I guess the question is whether you think ^ or + is simpler, and whether `num % 2` or `num & 1U` is simpler.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Mainly I felt that XOR is a less intuitive operation.